# Can I hash two strings into one hash?

Tags: python, hash, sha256

I am pretty new to Python and wanted to create some code which hashed together two strings. In particular for my case I wanted to hash the hash of a file and a Bitcoins Blocks hash. The code bellow obviously doesn't work as sha256() takes only one argument. Do you guys know anyway around this?

Thanks,

```
from __future__ import print_function
import blocktrail, time, csv, hashlib, sys

client = blocktrail.APIClient(api_key="x", api_secret="x", network="BTC", testnet=False)
address = client.address('x')

latest_block = client.block_latest()
hash_list = []
h = latest_block['hash']
sha256 = hashlib.sha256()
BUF_SIZE = 65536
print("test")

with open('entries#x.csv', 'rb') as entriesfile:
    buf = entriesfile.read(BUF_SIZE)
    while len(buf) > 0:
        sha256.update(buf)
        buf = entriesfile.read(BUF_SIZE)
    print(sha256.hexdigest())

entryhash = sha256.hexdigest()

hashofhe = hashlib.sha256(b'entryhash', 'h')
```

Comment: What does "together" mean?

Comment: Into one hash, ill change the title now.

Comment: Why not just concatenate the two strings and call sha256 on that?

Comment: What does "into one hash" mean?

Comment: You need to decide what you mean by "hash together".  Do you want to hash the concatenation of the two items?

Hash is defined on a single string, integer, or other "hashable" item.  There are myriad hash functions in the world.  What is it that you're trying to do with the return value?

Comment: I would like to take the hexadecimal hash I have made of the input file and the hexadecimal hash from the bitcoin block and create a final hexadecimal hash based of these two. Concatenating the two items and then hashing the string would do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just concatenate the two strings then hash that.

Answer (score 11):

Just a comment on this as I was looking for advice on the same subject:

- Concatenating the two strings and hashing is not necessarily a good idea as you can have easy collisions: `"hello", "world"` will have the same hash as `"hel", "loworld"`.
- If you know your strings well, you can find a neat separator to avoid this.
- Another option could be to prepend the size of each string before concatenation, so you would end up hashing `"5hello5world"` and `"3hel8loworld"` and is much less likely to generate collisions.
- If all you want is to implement `__hash__`, you could do `hash(hash(a) + hash(b))`.

Comment: This answer is far better. It should be the accepted one.